# Axis legends: aligning second line

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the basic R `plot` function (R 3.0.1 in Windows Vista Home Premium). I'm trying to make an axis legend with 2 lines, but the second line has strange alignment--I want it to be center aligned, which is usually the case, but the place I put the new line break seems to result in a right-align.

This code shows the problem I am having:

```
x11()
par(mar=c(5,6,1,1))
plot(1:5, 1:5, xlab='Nonsense', 
     ylab=expression(paste('A string followed by\n', this[stuff])))
```

When I plot the above, the second line of the y-axis code appears to be strangely right-aligned, which is undesirable--I'd much rather a center or even left-align. How can I change the alignment of this second line and still keep my subscript?

I do need the new line before the word with the subscript. I'd prefer to do this using `plot` if possible, since that is the plotting method with which I am most familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make a larger margin to get two lines of text to show up in the display.  I used your string as the axis label (including the new line to bump it outward and make room for the expression), then I added the expression separately using [?mtext](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/mtext.html):

```
windows()
  par(mai=c(1, 1, 0.5, 0))
  plot(1:5, 1:5, xlab='Nonsense', ylab='A string followed by\n')
  mtext(expression(this[stuff]), side=2, line=2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: This solved my orginal problem, but it creates a new one. I was wanting the part enclosed in the square brackets to end up as a subscript, as it does when paste is nested in expression.

Comment: Sorry about that, I hadn't actually read the plot. I have changed the answer; it's a workaround--I don't actually know what the bug is.